# Tumblr won't send 2FA code, so I can't login to my account

Tags: tumblr, multi-factor-auth

I've had a Tumblr account setup and running since about 2012. When they brought out 2-Factor Authentication (2FA) I enabled it on my account (I believe this was some time in 2014). 2FA via SMS worked fine for years (although a little slow on sending the SMS codes compared to Google / Dropbox etc..)

Recently I've tried to login to my account and it takes the username / password fine, but it never sends me the SMS code. I've tried resetting the password via a link they send to my email in an attempt to side step the 2FA SMS, but this also requires me to enter a 2FA code.

I'm essentially locked out of my account now, not through any fault of my own, but due to Tumblr not sending the 2FA codes.

The only way I still have access to the account is via some 3rd party integrations which automatically posts tweets from a linked twitter account which is done via IFTTT, but I can't actually get in to manage the account.

Any idea what can be done?

Comment: Don't suppose you have any "backup codes" written down anywhere?!